# Как из enum отобразить коды городов в выпадающем списке, используя специализированные шаблоны @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь сделать упрощенный вариант телефонного справочника, и у меня не получается отобразить в выпадающем списке имена перечислений кодов городов, то есть моя **модель** выглядит следующим образом:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class User
{
    public string CodeCountry { get; set; }
    public string CodeUser { get; set; }
    public CityCode CodeCity { get; set; }
}
public enum CityCode
{
    [Display(Name = "495")]
    One,
    [Display(Name = "351")]
    Two,
    [Display(Name = "812")]
    Three
}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.CodeCountry = "+7";
        user.CodeUser = "123456789";
        user.CodeCity = CityCode.Two;
        return View(user);
    }

}
```

**Вьюшка:**

```
@model MVC_Fund6_1.Models.User
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>EditorFor</h2>

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.CodeCountry)<br />
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CodeCountry) <br />

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.CodeCity)<br />
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CodeCity,"UserTemplate") <br />

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.CodeUser)<br />
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CodeUser)
```

**Специализированное представление UserTemplate:**

```
@using MVC_Fund6_1.Models
@model CityCode
<select id="CityCode" name="CityCode">
@foreach (CityCode value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CityCode)))
{

    <option value="@value">
        @value
    </option>
}
</select>
```

В итоге я не могу добиться, чтобы в выпадающем списке кодов городов выпадали именно имена, то есть не "One,two,three",а "495,351,812":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть, подскажите? Пробовал декорировать DataAnnotations в модели, но не получается. Пробовал присваивать имена перечислителю в модели и в специализированном шаблоне выводить через Enum.GetNames но тоже не получается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно провернуть такой трюк с помощью рефлексии:

Добавим в enum атрибут `Description` из `using System.ComponentModel;`

```
public enum CityCode
{
    [Description("495")]
    One,
    [Description("351")]
    Two,
    [Description("812")]
    Three
}
```

Чтоб получить значение из атрибута `Description` можно использовать следующий метод:

```
    static String GetNameFromDescription(Enum enumElement)
    {
        Type type = enumElement.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(enumElement.ToString());
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            Object[] attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
        return enumElement.ToString();
    }
```

рефакторинг данного метода:

```
static String GetNameFromDescription(Enum enumElement) => enumElement
        .GetType()
        .GetField(enumElement.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
        .Description;
```

или можно переписать в форме метода расширения:

```
    public static String GetNameFromDescription(this Enum enumElement)
    {
        Type type = enumElement.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(enumElement.ToString());
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            Object[] attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
        return enumElement.ToString();
    }
```

рефакторинг данного метода:

```
public static String GetNameFromDescription(this Enum enumElement) => enumElement
        .GetType()
        .GetField(enumElement.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
        .Description;
```

Используем: `GetNameFromDescription(CityCode.Three)` или `CityCode.Three.GetNameFromDescription()`

Результат: `812`

Comment: Вау! Вот это круто! спасибо.

Comment: @Mikhail, пожалуйста) не забудьте +1